# RecyclerView - ¿ Por qué mis ítems se compactan al deslizar?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

**Ítems de mi recycler view:**

(Como se ve normalmente)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Como cambia al deslizar)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Explicación de las imágenes:**

En la primer imágen se observa a "Toby" que se encuentra ubicado en "Villa Ballester, Buenos Aires, Argentina". En la segunda imágen se observa que "Toby" se encuentra ubicado en "Villa Ballester, Buenos Aires," (*Nótese que el país **(Argentina)** desapareció*)

**Descripción del problema:**

Estoy trabajando con un **recycler view** al cual le cargo cuatro items (cuatro perros distintos). El problema surge cuando deslizo hasta el tercer o cuarto item, de modo tal que el primer item (toby) **desaparece de la pantalla** y es en este punto en el cual se encoje el **Card View** ya que la palabra "Argentina" desaparece.

**Adjunto el código XML de los ítems del recycler view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_animales"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F8F5F3"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_animales"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_nombre_animal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Toby"
            android:textColor="#252525"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:fontFamily="arimo"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_animales"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_edad"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_edad_negro"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt_edad"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txt_edad"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_edad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="0.5 años"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arimo"
            android:textColor="#252525"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_nombre_animal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_edad"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_localidad"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_ubicacion_negro"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt_localidad"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_localidad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Villa Ballester, Buenos Aires, Argentina"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arimo"
            android:textColor="#252525"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_extra"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_edad"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_extra"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_extra_negro"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt_extra"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_extra"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_extra"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="15 gr."
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arimo"
            android:textColor="#252525"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_edad"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_edad"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Alguien por favor que me ayude a identificar el problema. Muchas gracias por leer!**

Comment: La RecyclerView reutiliza el ViewHolder, en este caso al deslizar y volver, es probable que haya un problema al reciclar tu vista.  Estás usando wrap content en el width del texto con id txt_localidad, es mejor usar match parent para que cuando la vista se recicle, no tenga que recalcular el tamaño del TextView.  Pruébalo a ver si funciona.

Comment: Gracias por comentar Manuel. Lo acabo de probar y no funcionó. Pense que iba a funcionar. Todavía no descubro la solución!

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que el primer ítem tiene un tamaño más grande que el resto de items y, cuando te desplazas por la lista y vuelves, se está reciclando y el tamaño ahora es igual, pero claro, el texto queda fuera de la vista... con ConstraintLayout es fácil solucionarlo, con Relative tendría que investigar... intenta que el último TextView tenga un tamaño fijo, de esta manera cuando la vista se recicle, todas tendrán el mismo tamaño y se verá tu texto.

Con Constraint quedaría así:

```
      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/animals_location_text_iv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/animals_guideline_end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/animals_location_icon_iv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/animals_location_icon_iv"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            tools:text="Villa Ballester, \nBuenos Aires, \nArgentina" />
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Manuel. Probé almacenando las vistas adentro de un constraint layout y al text view le puse width="0dp" y aun así no funcionó :(. Sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: Error mío, prueba con el height también a 0dp, eso debe funcionar.